# Can xss attacks bypass InnerText?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I am trying to perform an XSS aon my friend's websites, but they all use innerText instead of innerHTML.

Is there anyway that I can bypass `innerText` and perform attacks like those that are possible with `innerHTML`?

Comment: Nope. `innerText` is safe (though `.textContent` behaves more consistently, and should be preferred in most situations)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

innerHTML is dangerous like Cross Site Scripting you mentioned because you can add javascript via your HTML like,

```
<img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" onload="javascript:alert('hacked')" />
```

so it is safe to use innerText instead.

so therefore, there is not a way to inject js into innerText.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).